# displaying custom error pages in asp.net mvc 2.0 on production site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i have developed a production site in godaddy server.Now i want to display a custom error page if there is any error occurs in the site.i have made following changes in the web.config file ,

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Areas/User/Views/Shared/Error">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Areas/User/Views/Shared/Error" />
    </customErrors>
```

But now if error occurs the server will display his default error page for 404 page.

Now i want to display my customised error page.Please tell me the entire steps to implement this in asp.net mvc 2.0.i,e is there any coding i have to write in then controllers or in the global.asax.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This line 
indicates that when the page is not found it will redirect to Error.aspx, You can create a view inside the share folder and design it as to what you desire and change the url say for example, 
you create this page

```
MyCustomErrorPage.aspx
```

inside the shared folder, then change the redirect page to

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="/Areas/User/Views/Shared/MyCustomErrorPage" />
```